# Convolution with a polynomial is a polynomial. Why?

Tags: calculus, convolution

> Let $P:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\deg P=N$. Let $f$, an integrable-$2\pi$-periodic function. Show that $f\star P$ is also a polynomial.

So we can prove it for an arbitrary $x^n$ (Since a linear combination of polynomial is obviously a polynomial).

$$f\star P = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x-t)t^n \ dt$$

It looks like I don't have any other information in order to proceed.
What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried integral by part?

Comment: What $2\pi$ periodic functions are integrable on $\Bbb R$?  The only one I can think of is the zero function.

Comment: @SiXUlm , $f$ doesn't have to be differentiable

Comment: @GregoryGrant, what about $\sin x$?

Comment: @Elimination $\sin x$ is not integrable on $\Bbb R$. Do you perhaps mean integrable over one period $[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: I think it's enough for $f$ to be integrable for every closed interval.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use that convolution is commutative and linear, so it suffices to prove this for $P=x^n$. Then $$f\star P = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)(x-t)^n dt$$

Now expand $(x-t)^n$ using the binomial theorem, and you'll get that $f\star P$ is a polynomial with coefficients of the form $$(-1)^k \binom nk\int_0^{2\pi} f(t)t^k dt$$

Answer (score 5):

First notice that the all $C^{\infty}$ solutions of the differential equation $ y^{(N+1)}=0$ are polynomials.
$\\ $
We know that convolution of an $C^{\infty}$ function is again $C^{\infty}$.

From commutativity and dominated convergence we see that $$(f\ast P)^{(N+1)} =(P\ast f )^{(N+1)}=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int _{0}^{2\pi} (P(x-t))^{(N+1)}f(t)\rm{d}t=0,$$
hence we conclude the result.